# Jest async test timing out in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, asynchronous, jestjs

I need a little help with Jest testing running in a docker container. Please find my repo [here](https://github.com/samisagit/node-cms/blob/canned-all-potentially-frontend-vue-related-stuff-DANGER/src/services/tests/users.test.js) (this is the only branch with existing tests). I am running two tests, the first of which works fine, the second has a jasmine timeout error after 2 seconds. Now if I go through the motions, call the API and hit the [function](https://github.com/samisagit/node-cms/blob/6416ff5683c9f1d83f3f58b996ce8bb4df0f8223/src/services/users.js#L14) that I'm testing all is dandy, the user gets created and a user Object is returned - however the test just seems to fail as soon as it hits the below.

```
await internals.checkUserIsUnique(data.email)
```

I have tried returning true above this, which causes the test to fail (which makes sense) but as soon as we hit async code it will end up timing out.

```
FAIL  src/services/tests/users.test.js

  ✓ Tests running (2ms)
  ✕ Creates user (2007ms)

  ● Creates user

Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 2000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

at node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queue_runner.js:72:21
at Timeout.callback [as _onTimeout] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:633:19)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.462s
Ran all test suites.
```

Now I'm not sure if this issue is caused by something idiotic I've done in my actual node functionality (which wouldn't surprise me, only it seems to work outside of tests) or if I've botched the Jest setup somehow (seems most plausible) or this issue is actually coming from the fact that the code is running in Docker. Any help would be much appreciated.

Any further info needed please ask!

**Edit**

As per the below suggestion (thanks stijndepestel) I've tried this outside of docker, same issue so evidently not that. Had to point this at a remote DB so not that connection either.

Comment: If you suspect the issue arises from the tests running in docker, have you tried running it outside of a container? You might at least eliminate that as the cause.

Comment: okay, not docker, just tried this from a straight yarn start and the same result.